# Using lightning:listview's filter as a standalone component to query records

Tags: list-view, filters, lightninglistview

Is it possible to use the filter logic of the lightning:listview as a standalone component to query records? I am trying to use these queried records to generate events for fullcalendar. Or another option, is it possible to get the records queried by the listview?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Aura, that is not possible with the `lightning:listview`. You can see the records, edit them, but cannot access them programmatically.

In LWC, there is an API called `getListUi(beta)`, using which you can get the records of the listview.

Here is an example.

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getListUi } from 'lightning/uiListApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';

export default class Example extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getListUi, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT, listViewApiName: 'AllAccounts' })
    propertyOrFunction;
}
```

Full details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_get_list_ui).

Comment: Does the `lightning/uiListApi` come with built in filtering or is this something I will have to create as well?

Comment: @FrankyJiang It filters records based on filters of the selected list view